# Can UWF be enabled for a specific user

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-v1607, uwf

Is it possible to enable the UWF (Unified Write Filter) for a specific user on Windows 10 IoT?

The docs don't seem to mention this ability...

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/customize/enterprise/unified-write-filter

I have a device where one user (An "Administrator" user) should be able to perform different tasks like installing software, etc., but the main application runs under a different "Guest" user for which I would like to have the write filters enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if the answer is worth anything to you after a few months:
No, I don't see how UWF can be configured per user. uwfmgr works only system-wide. What you could do for your use case is to use [AppLocker](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-defender-application-control/applocker/applocker-overview), an application whitelisting solution which can be configured on a per-user basis. You could deny the guest user certain programs or msi installers or configure a whitelist of known programs the Guest user is allowed to start.